# Errors passing char to functions

Tags: c, function, makefile, header, char

I'm trying to pass a char to a function but am getting errors when doing it. 
This is the main function that I have

```
#include "maiello8_headers_P1.h"

int main()
{
        int characterCount;
        int wordCount;
        int lineCount;
        char fileName[20];

        printf("Enter the name of the text file: ");
        scanf("%s\n",fileName);


        characterCount = countCharacters(fileName);
        wordCount = countWords(fileName);
        lineCount = countLines(fileName);

        printf("Characters: %d\n", characterCount);
        printf("Words: %d\n", wordCount);
        printf("Lines: %d\n", lineCount);

        return 0;
}
```

The error that I am getting is

```
maiello8_main_P1.c: In function ‘main’:
maiello8_main_P1.c:20:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘countCharacters’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   20 |  characterCount = countCharacters(fileName);
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~
      |                                   |
      |                                   char *
In file included from maiello8_main_P1.c:9:
maiello8_headers_P1.h:8:26: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
    8 | int countCharacters(char fileName);
      |                     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

But when I change the program to characterCount = countCharacters(char *fileName);
 or characterCount = countCharacters(char* fileName); I get an error saying "expected expression before char. So I'm not sure whether the problem is in the main function of the countCharacters function.This is the countCharacters function

```
#include "maiello8_headers_P1.h"

int countCharacters(char fileName)
{
        char currentCharacter;                      
        int numCharacters = 0;                      
        FILE *fpt;                          
        fpt = fopen(fileName,"r");                  

        while((currentCharacter = fgetc(fileName)) != EOF)      
        {
                if(currentCharacter != ' ' && currentCharacter != '\n') 
                        numCharacter++;                 

        }
        fclose(fileName);                       

        return numCharacter;                        
}
```

I am using Makefile for this program so the problem could also be in the header which is:

```
#ifndef pH
#define pH

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int countCharacters(char fileName);
int countWords(char fileName);
int countLines(char fileName);

#endif
```

I'm sorry for putting so much code but I'm new to C and have been at this for hours looking at similar problems and can't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filename` is, unsurprisingly, a "string": that is, an array of characters:

```
char fileName[20];
```

(That's very little space for a filename, don't you think? Your header file's name, `maiello8_headers_P1.h`, is 21 characters long, so it would require at least 22 characters in the array, and that's assuming that you never add a directory path. Be a bit more generous. You have several billion bytes of memory in your machine; reserving a few thousand for a filepath won't break the bank :-) But I digress.)

In C, you can't actually pass arrays as parameters. You have to pass a pointer to the first element. The compiler helps you out with this by automatically changing an array argument to a pointer to the first element in the array. That's called "decaying", a term you will encounter sooner or later.

So your functions are called with a pointer to the first element in `filename`. That element is a `char`, so the type of the decayed argument is `char *`. But your header declares:

```
int countCharacters(char fileName);
```

In other words, the header says that the argument to `countCharacters` is a single character.

When you declare a function, C believes what you say. So it expects that you will call the function with a single character. In C, characters are just small integers, and a small integer is certainly not what your function should be expecting. So the compiler attempts to reduce the pointer to the first character in `filename` into a small integer, by dropping all but the last byte of the pointer's value. Since that's almost certainly not what you wanted, the compiler warns you that you're probably doing something other than what you thought you were doing.

You get full points for requesting compiler warnings (if you requested them, rather than being given a Makefile which did that for you.) Compilers are under no obligation to warn you about things like this, which are actually legal C even though they make no sense, and GCC won't provide the warnings unless you ask it to explicitly. It's one of the few concessions to human weakness you will find in a C compiler, and it's best to take full advantage of it.

In short, fix the declaration of your functions, both in the header file and in the implementation file. A good choice is

```
int countCharacters(const char* fileName);
```

which not only has the correct type, but also indicates that the function will not modify the value of the characters pointed to by its argument.

Comment: Thank  you for the explanation. It's much easier for me to understand now

Comment: @MarcoAiello: I assume you noticed and corrected `fgetc(fileName)` and `fclose(fileName)`. Those will also trigger compiler diagnostics, since the library functions expect `FILE*`, not `char*` (and much less `char`).